# get element by id returns null for elements that were dynamically added using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function createInput(id){

    count++;
    var name = "name" + count;

    var text = "#" + id.id;
    var newInput = "<input type='text' id='" + name + "' placeholder='' />";


    var myTextArea = document.getElementById(id.id);
    myTextArea.innerHTML += newInput;

    return false;
}
```

The above function adds an input type to a textarea in a div in my code. Once the input type is displayed dynamically, i try to get it's element id using `getElementById` but it returns null. May I know what is going wrong here? It seems that the new input type is added but somehow the input type is null.

Also, when i refresh the page, i realize the newly added input type disappears. Any way to force the new dynamic input type to remain in the page?

Comment: How are you calling the function? Is `id` an object with a `id` property ?

Comment: can u post the full code, where u are trying to access the elment

Comment: The question doesn't seems to be completely clear can you, please, create a working example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: As a sidenote, how exactly does one add an input to a textarea element ?

Comment: id gives me the textarea's id.

Comment: myTextArea.innerHTML += newInput; //adds the input type into text area

Comment: @dqf13g32g Why did you remove the last paragraph? The edit suggestion did end up getting through, but I'd like to understand why you did that. Your edit comments didn't explain or even mention that part.

Comment: @Adi Inbar Im sorry that was a fail i correct this

Comment: @dqf13g32g In other words, the three other reviewers were sleepwalking. That doesn't surprise me. It seems to happen a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamically created content is only temporary on the page. When page is refreshed it is again without it. You should recreate it again on a page [onload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)  or  [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (store the information in a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [HTML5 storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)).

I tried to create working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/G2PKF/1/.

```
<div id="area1" onclick="createInput(this)" ></div>
<br/>
<div id="area2" onclick="createInput(this)"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('name' + count));alert(document.getElementById('name' + count).outerHTML)" value="Access Last Element" />
```

When a rectangle is clicked an input is added to it. The button allows to display last element added.

**Everything works as expected. I don't see any problem with your function.**